# Remove number from large string in specific position [PHP RegEx]

Tags: php, regex

I have a large string (multiple lines) I need to find numbers in with regex. The position the number I need is always proceeded/follow by an exact order of characters so I can use non-capturing matches to pinpoint the exact number I need. I put together a regex to get this number but it refuses to work and I can't figure it out!

Below is a small bit of php code that I can't get to work showing the basic format of what i need

```
$sTestData = 'lak sjdhfklsjaf<?kjnsdfh461uihrfkjsn+%5Bmlknsadlfjncas dlk';

$sNumberStripRE = '/.*?(?:sjdhfklsjaf<\\?kjnsdfh)(\\d+)(?:uihrfkjsn\\+%5Bmlknsadlfjncas).*?/gim';

if (preg_match_all($sNumberStripRE, $sTestData, $aMatches))
{
    var_dump($aMatches);
}
```

the number I need is 461 and the characters before/after the spaces on either side of this number are always the same

any help getting the above regex working would be great!

This link [RegExr: My Reg Ex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2sl92) (to an online regex genereator and my regex) shows that it should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g` is an invalid modifier, drop it.

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/ptT4n)

Comment: I fixed the code in the example (just a typo) but it still doesn't work and I do have a g modifier or could you be more specific on what you mean

Comment: @Tristan: remove the `g` modifier. It's invalid.

Comment: excellent it was the g that was causing the issue! that RegExr uses a g modifier thats why i did

Answer (score 1):

With regard to that link, which regular expression engine is it working from?  Built in Flex, so probably the ActionScript RegExp engine.  They are not all the same, each one varies.

You have a number of double-backslashes, they should probably be single in those strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sTestData = 'lak sjdhfklsjaf<?kjnsdfh461uihrfkjsn+%5Bmlknsadlfjncas dlk';
$lDelim = ' sjdhfklsjaf<?kjnsdfh';
$rDelim = 'uihrfkjsn+%5Bmlknsadlfjncas ';
$start = strpos($sTestData, $lDelim) + strlen($lDelim);
$length = strpos($sTestData, $rDelim) - $start;
$number = substr($sTestData, $start, $length);
```

Comment: Thats one way of doing it but there are multiple of this numbers I need to extract and its a little clunky doing it this way

Comment: You can explode() the string at $lDelim and do substr($chunk, 0, strpos($chunk, rDelim)) on each chunk. Still clunky though.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can accomplish your goal with the following code:

```
   $string='lak sjdhfklsjaf<?kjnsdfh461uihrfkjsn+%5Bmlknsadlfjncas dlk';
   if (preg_match('/(sjdhfklsjaf<\?kjnsdfh)(\d+)(uihrfkjsn\+%5Bmlknsadlfjncas)/', $string, $num_array)) {
   $aMatches = $num_array[2];
   } else {
   $aMatches = "";
   }
   echo $aMatches;
```

Explanation:
I declared a variable entitled $string and made it equal to the variable you initially presented. You indicated that the characters on either side of the numeric value of interest were always the same. I assigned the numerical value of interest to $aMatches by setting $aMatches equal to back reference 2. Using the parentheses in regex you will get 3 matches: backreference 1 which will contain the characters before the number, backreference 2 which will contain the numbers that you want, and backreference 3 which is the stuff after the number. I assigned $num_array as the variable name for those backreferences and the [2] indicates that it is the second backreference. So, $num_array[1] would contain the match in backreference 1 and $num_array[3] would contain the match in backreference 3.

Here is the explanation of my regular expression:
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(sjdhfklsjaf<\?kjnsdfh)»
   Match the characters “sjdhfklsjaf<” literally «sjdhfklsjaf<»
   Match the character “?” literally «\?»
   Match the characters “kjnsdfh” literally «kjnsdfh»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\d+)»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 3 «(uihrfkjsn+%5Bmlknsadlfjncas)»
   Match the characters “uihrfkjsn” literally «uihrfkjsn»
   Match the character “+” literally «+»
   Match the characters “%5Bmlknsadlfjncas” literally «%5Bmlknsadlfjncas»

Hope this helps and best of luck to you.
Steve